# Special character (e.g. *) used in synonym.txt file not working in solr

Tags: solr, special-characters, solr4, synonym

For solr with version 4.10.4 search, I have created file synonyms.txt and apply synonymFilterFactory as follows :

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField">  
     <analyzer>     
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" preserveOriginal="1" stemEnglishPossessive="0"/>
     </analyzer>
     <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

synonyms.txt has below content:

```
holland* => holland

holland, netherland, netherlands, niederlande
```

I have certain conditions in application that generate term as :
`holland*`

In this situation, I want to display the same result as I would get when I put the terms `holland`, `netherland`, `netherlands`, `niederlande`.

But currently, for term holland*, it dosn't giving matching results.
Results for holland* contains results as that for terms 'holland' or 'netherland' but those are at the bottom, so can we boost those results?

Does any one have any idea, how can I achieve that?

Below are few more details :

In case of holland, I get some results and when I debug the query, it shows as

```
"debug": {
    "rawquerystring": "holland",
    "querystring": "holland",
    "parsedquery": "(name:holland name:netherland name:netherlands name:niederlande)/no_coord",
    "parsedquery_toString": "name:holland name:netherland name:netherlands name:niederlande",
    "explain": {
      "country-NLD-de": "\n7.42217 = (MATCH) sum of:\n  7.42217 = (MATCH) weight(name:niederlande in 1775593) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:\n    7.42217 = score(doc=1775593,freq=1.0), product of:\n      0.5213204 = queryWeight, product of:\n        14.237252 = idf(docFreq=14, maxDocs=8413113)\n        0.036616646 = queryNorm\n      14.237252 = fieldWeight in 1775593, product of:\n        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n          1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n        14.237252 = idf(docFreq=14, maxDocs=8413113)\n        1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=1775593)\n",
      "country-NLD-en": "\n7.3550315 = (MATCH) sum of:\n  7.3550315 = (MATCH) weight(name:netherlands in 230095) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:\n    7.3550315 = score(doc=230095,freq=1.0), product of:\n      0.5189572 = queryWeight, product of:\n        14.172713 = idf(docFreq=15, maxDocs=8413113)\n        0.036616646 = queryNorm\n      14.172713 = fieldWeight in 230095, product of:\n        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n          1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n        14.172713 = idf(docFreq=15, maxDocs=8413113)\n        1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=230095)\n",
      "place-49218-de": "\n5.0385056 = (MATCH) sum of:\n  5.0385056 = (MATCH) weight(name:holland in 385574) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:\n    5.0385056 = score(doc=385574,freq=1.0), product of:\n      0.4295267 = queryWeight, product of:\n        11.730367 = idf(docFreq=183, maxDocs=8413113)\n        0.036616646 = queryNorm\n      11.730367 = fieldWeight in 385574, product of:\n        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n          1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n        11.730367 = idf(docFreq=183, maxDocs=8413113)\n        1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=385574)\n",
```

In case of holland*, results contain some records from holland but debug part is as follows :

```
"debug": {
    "rawquerystring": "holland*",
    "querystring": "holland*",
    "parsedquery": "name:holland*",
    "parsedquery_toString": "name:holland*",
    "explain": {
      "place-51432-de": "\n1.0 = (MATCH) ConstantScore(name:holland name:hollandarod name:hollande name:hollander name:hollanderei name:hollandia name:hollandischer name:hollands name:hollandsbjerg name:hollandsch name:hollandsche name:hollandscheveld name:hollandsdiep name:hollandskamp name:hollandske), product of:\n  1.0 = boost\n  1.0 = queryNorm\n",
      "place-49196-de": "\n1.0 = (MATCH) ConstantScore(name:holland name:hollandarod name:hollande name:hollander name:hollanderei name:hollandia name:hollandischer name:hollands name:hollandsbjerg name:hollandsch name:hollandsche name:hollandscheveld name:hollandsdiep name:hollandskamp name:hollandske), product of:\n  1.0 = boost\n  1.0 = queryNorm\n",
      "place-49207-de": "\n1.0 = (MATCH) ConstantScore(name:holland name:hollandarod name:hollande name:hollander name:hollanderei name:hollandia name:hollandischer name:hollands name:hollandsbjerg name:hollandsch name:hollandsche name:hollandscheveld name:hollandsdiep name:hollandskamp name:hollandske), product of:\n  1.0 = boost\n  1.0 = queryNorm\n",
```

In above dubug section, if we check "parsedquery" part, it's different in case of holland and holland*.
So I think, special character * not working for SynonymFilterFactory.

Comment: Have you tried applying the synonym filter at index time as well? I don't think the wildcard processing at query time works with the synonyms.

Comment: @MattMcKnight : Yes I have tried it at index time, but no success

Comment: I also have the similar problem, would be really appreciable if someone can help us.

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding, the synonyms file doesn't support wildcards.

In your case, you could also have another problem, because the wildcard in query are commonly used to search for results that are not exact matches.
It depends from the query parser used in your query.

In other words the query "holland*" search all the documents having a term starting with "holland".

If you want Solr treat the wildcard as a simple character you should escape it.

Another error I see, in your field definition you should define the `analyzer` type for both the case (index and query).

> If you provide a simple  definition for a field type, as in
> the examples above, then it will be used for both indexing and
> queries.

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```